# Canvas shape inner shadow + blending mode

Tags: javascript, canvas, blending

so this has been driving me crazy for the past few days.

I'm trying to replicate Photoshop's inner shadow in JS with different blending modes like `overlay`.

There are easy ways to add shadows to shapes like `ctx.shadowBlur` or `ctx.filter = 'drop-shadow(...)'`, but these only generate outer shadows. You can create inner shadow with some composition magic with `xor`, but this leaves the image with not smooth edges (I guess `xor` doesn't handle anti-alias really well), like in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/89pes8ap/1/

So, I had another idea that kind of worked, because it used `xor` only once:

https://jsfiddle.net/3cnwtvyj/

But as you can see the `overlay`-ed version still doesn't have smooth edges.

So, my question is this: how can you add smooth inner shadow with different blending modes that could work with all kinds of shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Composite Operations do work on the alpha channel, and hence don't go well with shadows.

Unfortunately, I think there is not much you can do to circumvent this for your shadow over transparent background, moreover for a circle.

One little thing I can see though is that you actually don't need the xor part, and can replace it with a path composed of a rect and an arc that you'd fill as 'evenodd'. This will create the hole directly, reducing *a little bit* antialiasing artifacts.

```js
drawOP();
drawEvenOdd();



function drawEvenOdd() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('evenodd');
  canvas.width = 150;
  canvas.height = 200;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';

  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10 * 2;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  // will draw an hole
  ctx.fill('evenodd');

  // remove shadow
  ctx.shadowColor = 'transparent';
  ctx.shadowBlur = ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.fill('evenodd');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fillText('evenodd', 100, 180)
}

function drawOP() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('OP')
  canvas.width = 150;
  canvas.height = 200;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';

  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor'

  ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()

  ctx.filter = 'drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black)'
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)
  ctx.filter = 'none';
  ctx.fillText('OP', 100, 180)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="OP"></canvas>
<canvas id="evenodd"></canvas>
```